# google maps api not work inside samsung knox container

Tags: android, google-maps, samsung-knox

We are developing an App that use google maps api in a knox container and every time the application will be opened the message is "you must have to install google play services before use App", when we put the application outside knox it works fine.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, based from document for [Support Samsung Knox](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/faq/can-i-push-google-maps-knox-container):

> ## Can I push Google Maps to the KNOX container?
>
> The KNOX container currently doesn't support Google Maps. You can enable GPS, but it will be enabled for the entire device and not just for the KNOX container.